# Proton VPN is not installing due to CURL error! Why?

Tags: linux, vpn, fedora, curl, dnf

I have Fedora 38 and I want to install protonVPN. I followed the guide and downloaded the respective rpm package but when I try to install it or update dnf I receive this error:
[CODE]ProtonVPN Fedora Stable repository                                                                                                                                                                            0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'protonvpn-fedora-stable':

- Curl error (60): SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK for https://repo.protonvpn.com/fedora-38-stable/repodata/repomd.xml [SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate in certificate chain]
  Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'protonvpn-fedora-stable': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
  Ignoring repositories: protonvpn-fedora-stable
  Last metadata expiration check: 2:45:09 ago on Mon 05 Jun 2023 05:35:41 PM EDT.
  Dependencies resolved.
  Nothing to do.
  Complete!
  [main@fedora Downloads]$ [/CODE]
  [B][CENTER]

"The error message you're receiving indicates a problem with the SSL certificate for the ProtonVPN repository. More specifically, the error "SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate in certificate chain" suggests that there's a self-signed certificate somewhere in the certificate chain, which is generally considered insecure and can't be verified.

> Here are a few possible solutions:
>
> 1. **Verify Your System Time**: An incorrect system time can cause SSL errors. Check to make sure your system time is accurate.
> 2. **Try Disabling SSL Verification Temporarily**: This isn't recommended for long-term solutions because it can leave your system
>    vulnerable. But, for a quick fix or to see if SSL verification is the
>    issue, you can try this. You'll need to modify your DNF configuration
>    file to disable SSL verification. Here's how:
>
>    Open the DNF configuration file in a text editor with root permissions. For example, you can use `sudo` with `nano` like this:
>
>    ```bash
>    sudo nano /etc/dnf/dnf.conf
>    ```
>
>    Then, add or modify the `sslverify` line to be `False`:
>
>    ```bash
>    sslverify=False
>    ```
>
>    Save and exit the file. Then try running `sudo dnf update` again.
>
>    Remember to set `sslverify` back to `True` once you're done to keep your system secure.
> 3. **Contact ProtonVPN Support**: If none of the above solutions work, there might be an issue with the repository or the certificate that
>    ProtonVPN needs to fix. Reach out to their support for help.
>
> Remember, solution 2 is not recommended for long-term use as it
> disables SSL verification, which can leave your system vulnerable.
> It's primarily a troubleshooting step to help determine where the
> issue is coming from."[/CENTER][/B]

**How can I address this?**